# React Native Scrollview not scrolling

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```
<Native.ImageBackground source={props.background ? props.background : background} resizeMode={props.background ? 'cover' : 'repeat'} imageStyle={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
    <Native.StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
    <Native.View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Native.ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow: 1}}>
        <Native.View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Components.RestaurantMenu
            menuPassed={this.state.menuReceived[0]}
            orderChange={this.orderObjectChange}
            orderObject={this.state.orderObject}
          />
        </Native.View>
      </Native.ScrollView>
    </Native.View>
</Native.ImageBackground>
```

Hello I have this code but it fortunately does not scroll the menu what could be the problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes Process to follow the scrollview: It will be working on the list of view of inner loops. So you need to do like that.

```
<ScrollView> 
 <View style={{flex : 1}}>
    <View>
      <Text>Any text Here </Text>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text>Any text 2 Here </Text>
    </View>
</View>
</ScrollView>
```

Set scrollview out from the all other views then try:)